# Jest encountered an unexpected token while using Typescript, React and SPFx

Tags: spfx

```
describe('Enzyme basics', () => {

  let reactComponent: ReactWrapper<ICrudProps>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    reactComponent = mount(React.createElement(
      Crud,
      {
        spHttpClient: {},
        siteUrl: 'bogus',
        description: 'bogus'
      }
    ));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    reactComponent.unmount();
  });

  it('should root web part element exists', () => {

    // define the css selector
    let cssSelector: string = '#iceCreamShop';

    // find the element using css selector
    const element = reactComponent.find(cssSelector);
    expect(element.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });

});
```

I am trying to run this test, but for some reason Jest is throwing me an error.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\github\crud-simple-test\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-http\lib\index.js:12
    export { default as HttpClient } from './httpClient/HttpClient';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export



      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1059:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/webparts/crud/components/Todolist/Todolist.tsx:7025:27)

  console.log src/webparts/crud/components/Store/reducers.ts:486
    action type @@redux/INIT3.m.1.6.8.p is not found
```

I've tried various stuffs, but I have no idea how to fix this. This is my package.json. I am using a Typescript React application using SPFx. I think it's an issue with Microsoft library in particular, but maybe it's just some config issue.

This is my jest configuration inside package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],

    "transformIgnorePatterns": [ "/node_modules/" ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testMatch": [
      "**/src/**/*.test.+(ts|tsx|js)"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "lcov",
      "text",
      "cobertura"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/jest",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-junit",
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 100,
        "functions": 100,
        "lines": 100,
        "statements": 100
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, it seems to be related to the fact that I am using Typescript, but the error doesn't tell me what exactly is the problem and what I should exactly do with my config file. In fact, I think the log is misleading, because the second error points to a js file and not a ts file.